# How to make the commission for withdrawal of Bitcoin on the exchange consistent with the miner’s fee viewed on the blockchain browser

Tags: transaction-fees

I transferred Bitcoin on the exchange and found that the fee charged for filling in is inconsistent with the miner’s fee viewed in the blockchain browser. How do I ensure consistency? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The fee your exchange is charging you is the fee for their services, which includes the miner fee that they need to pay on your behalf.

It is normal that this number is higher than what you view on the block chain explorer.